# The function table.setColumnLayout(columnSettings); is not working for me

Tags: tabulator

I've written a function to create tables with different column setups and different data based on the parameters I send it. That all works fine.

My problem is that I can't get the `setColumnLayout` function to work when I want to reconfigure the existing table with new data and column settings. I know that the column settings are correct because they work for table creation.

The code, `table.clearData();` , in the top section works normally.

I'm also unable to get the destroy function to work. As far as I could tell that is for Tabulator 3.0.

I am using Mac Chrome 76 and Tabulator 4.3.

Any help letting me know what I'm doing wrong would be apreciated.

Thanks, Mike

```js
function  createTable (tabledata,SelectedColumnSettings){                   

     $("#clear").click(function(){
        table.clearData();

         var columnSettings = [
            {title:"id", field:"id", visible:false},
            {title:"Company", field:"Company Name", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Name", field:"Name", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Word Count Rate", field:"Word Count Rate", sorter:"number",  align:"center"},
            {title:"Hourly Rate", field:"Hourly Rate", sorter:"number",  align:"center"},
            {title:"Resourced", field:"Resourced", sorter:"number",  align:"center"},
            {title:"Language Source", field:"Language Source", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Profile Picture", field:"Profile Picture", align:"center"},
            {title:"Completed Projects", field:"Completed Projects", sorter:"number",  align:"center"}];

       // var columnSettings=getColumnSettings("Contacts");
        table.setColumnLayout(columnSettings);
     });


        var columnSettings=getColumnSettings(SelectedColumnSettings); // get the settings for the selected list

        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {

        height:600, // set height of table to enable virtual DOM

        resizableColumns:false, // this option takes a boolean value (default = true)

        data:tabledata, //load initial data into table
        layout:"fitDataFill", //fit columns to width of table (optional)

        columns: columnSettings,  //Define Table Columns. Sets columns for the different lists projects, contacts....

       });

  };    // end create table
```

I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: If you add full code with table data we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

`setColumnLayout` needs to be done in conjunction with `getColumnLayout`. Not sure where `SelectedColumnSettings` is coming from. Also `getColumnSettings` is a property of a table and I do see it being called that way:

```
var columnSettings=getColumnSettings(SelectedColumnSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  Set Column

```
         var columnSettings = [
            {title:"id", field:"id", visible:false},
            {title:"Company", field:"Company Name", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Name", field:"Name", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Word Count Rate", field:"Word Count Rate", sorter:"number",  align:"center"},
            {title:"Hourly Rate", field:"Hourly Rate", sorter:"number",  align:"center"},
            {title:"Resourced", field:"Resourced", sorter:"number",  align:"center"},
            {title:"Language Source", field:"Language Source", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Profile Picture", field:"Profile Picture", align:"center"},
            {title:"Completed Projects", field:"Completed Projects", sorter:"number",  align:"center"}];

       // var columnSettings=getColumnSettings("Contacts");

   table.setColumn(columnSettings);
```